# Creating checkbox using titanium alloy

Tags: android, sdk, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I am new in Titanium alloy and I would like to change my project from titanium default template to alloy. Below is the code for creating a text box in default template. I would like to change this to alloy template.

```
    var checkbox = Ti.UI.createSwitch({
   id:'checkbox',
   style:Ti.UI.Android.SWITCH_STYLE_CHECKBOX,
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Not hard at all! Try this inside your Alloy XML view markup:

*checkbox.xml*

```
<Alloy>
    <Switch id="checkbox"/>
</Alloy>
```

Now we can use the style file to set attributes based on the id.

*checkbox.tss*

```
"#checkbox[platform=android]" : {
    style:Ti.UI.Android.SWITCH_STYLE_CHECKBOX
}
```

This will set the style to checkbox, also note that I set this to only happen for android.
Alternatively, if we wanted every switch to be of the checkbox style we could set this inside *app.tss*:

```
"Switch" : {
    style:Ti.UI.Android.SWITCH_STYLE_CHECKBOX
}
```

Comment: this is very helpful information,please share something about associating some text of lable with checkbox, how can I have two separate view element associated?

Comment: Hello,
Can you please tell how to change default green color to something else. Right know it looks its not changeable to other

Answer (score 1):

You can create the check box like this.

```
var checkbox = Ti.UI.createSwitch({
  style: Ti.UI.Android.SWITCH_STYLE_CHECKBOX,
  textAlign:Ti.UI.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_LEFT,
  title:'Notice Me',
  value:true,
  width: 300,
  left: 18
});
win.add(checkbox);

checkbox.addEventListener('change',function(e){
  //function
  Ti.API.info('Switch value: ' + checkbox.value);
});
```